# Jmeter and Jenkins Integration to generate Perfmon graph

Tags: apache, jenkins, jmeter-5.0

I want to measure CPU and Memory usage of my server during a load test using [Jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org) and [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) integration, is that possible?

If yes, then please let me know the process.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you try something by yourself? We are willing to help but unfortunately your question is pretty wide.

Comment: I want to measure CPU and Memory usage of my server during load test using Jmeter. For this, I added a "jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector" listener with my scripts in JMeter GUI and configured JMeter perfmon plugin in my server. I got the graph in JMeter GUI correctly without any errors.

Now I want to run my same JMeter script via  Jenkins for continuous Integration (Without opening JMeter GUI).